# How to restrict credit card number displaying as plain text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my project I am working with activemerchant gem where when I give credit card number it is stored as "xxxx-xxx-xxx-1111". Here there is an issue. While we try to submit / input the details, in the log my credit card number is displayed (ex: 1111-1111-1212-1111) as plain text but while storing in database it is fine.

While entering itself I want to see number in the log as "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-1111". How it can be possible? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

For this the best would be to use config.filter option (config/application.rb). For example password is automatically filtered. You can filter cc number so it appears as FILTERED, but if you want to add custom where you show last 4 when you can use labda operator in config.filter statement

```
config.filter_parameters << lambda do |k, v| 
  if k == 'cc_number'
    v.replace('[FILTER]') #here you cann add your logic to extract last 4
  end
end
```

For me I do not see any value in adding last 4, so simple filter would do on this field.

hope it helps